# Iterate through Map in ruby

Tags: ruby

How do I rewrite this Java statement in Ruby?

```
for (Map.Entry<byte[], HServerLoad.RegionLoad> entry : serverLoad.getRegionsLoad().entrySet()){
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Need sample example input and output too.. to help you :)

Comment: This empty `for` loop does not do anything so you don't need to rewrite it. Seriously though, what are you asking? Do you simply want to iterate over the values stored in an arbitrary map? Do you want to mimic whatever functionality this code provides in Java (some Hadoop-related stuff?)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you want to iterate a ruby map(hash) with key and values you could write

```
h.each { |k, v| puts "Key=#{k}, Value=#{v}" }
```